# Repeatedly flipping between two layout colors

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on an app in which I am trying to continuously flip between two colors of Layout (Linear Layout) , but the colors are not changing as expected. When I run the app, it waits  and only the color mentioned the last is changed and that too only once, I suspect that the layout is not able to change the color as soon as the application is trying to change its color, as a result the app is only able to change the color once.

Below is the code

flasher.java

```
package com.tutorial.flasher;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class flasher extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     LinearLayout llaLayout;
     int a,b = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        llaLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layo);

        for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            //SystemClock.sleep(2000);

            //llaLayout.buildDrawingCache()
            Thread.currentThread();
            try
            {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.notifyAll();

            }
            llaLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"));

            //SystemClock.sleep(2000);
            Thread.currentThread();
            try
            {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.notifyAll();

            }
            llaLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));

        //  SystemClock.sleep(2000);
        }
    }
}
```

I am only getting the Red color in the layout.

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `Handler`.
For example:

```
private boolean bool = true;
llaLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layo);
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                changeColor();              
            }
            private void changeColor() {
                if (bool) {
                    llaLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    bool = false;
                } else {
                   llaLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    bool  = true;
                }               
            }}, 1000);
```

This code will recursively call same function `changeColor()` where 1000 is time in milliseconds to call it next time.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't block in the main thread. That will immediately make your application unresponsive.

You could use a timer or a separate thread to do this. You just need to be sure to perform the actual UI-related function (`setBackgroundColor`) on the UI thread. For this, you could use `Activity.runOnUiThread`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to run the UI related function through Activity.runOnUiThread, but it didn't work as expected, This time I got only the first mentioned color (Red), here is the code snippet          , i replaced the setBackground method on layout by below mentioned section.      
         _activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
             public void run(){
              llaLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
              
             }
            });
         
 Thanks,Sid